# Missing tools.jar in JDK 8

Tags: java, tools.jar

i've got jdk-8u60-windows-x64.exe and jdk-8u60-windows-i586.exe.
Both are installed and JAVA_HOME points to the 64 bit version.
None of them got tools.jar in the lib folder as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html)
Does anyone know what is wrong with the installation?